# Can I use the L'Hospital rule on a multivariable limit after eliminating one variable from the expression?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I've been given this multivariable limit:

$$\lim_{[x,y] \to [0,0]} \frac{\tan(y\cdot \sin((x-1)y^2))}{y^3\,\ln(x)}$$

My solution of this problem is as follows:

$\lim_{[x,y] \to [0,0]} \frac{\tan(y\cdot \sin((x-1)y^2))}{y^3\,\ln(x)} \quad = \quad \lim_{[x,y] \to [0,0]} \frac{\tan(y\cdot \sin(y^2x-y^2))}{y^3\,\ln(x)} \quad \cdot \quad \frac{\sin(y^2x - y^2)}{\sin(y^2x - y^2)} \quad = \quad \lim_{[x,y] \to [0,0]} \frac{\sin(y^2x-y^2)\tan(y\cdot \sin(y^2x-y^2))}{y^3\, \sin(y^2x-y^2)\ln(x)} \quad = \quad \lim_{[x,y] \to [0,0]} \frac{\sin(y^2x-y^2)}{y^2\,\ln(x)} \cdot \frac{(x-1)}{(x-1)} \quad = \quad \lim_{[x,y]\to[0,0]} \frac{(x-1)}{\ln(x)}$

Now, at this point, we are left with a multivariable limit, however the $y$ variable has been eliminated from the expression. Using the L'Hospital rule, we would easily get the solution 0. My question: can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. More generally: if $f\colon\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is a function that doesn't depend upon the second variable (that is $f(x,y_1)$ is always equal to $f(x,y_2)$), then $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x,y_0)$ for any $y_0$ of your choice.